# How to assign a dynamic variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a code

```
 const test = "Networks"
 let onedata = JSON.parse(read_data);
 onedata[test]+'_keys' = "";   // Getting error as ; expected in =
```

I need to pass the test value into onedata.Networks_keys and assign as empty.

Comment: Have you tried `onedata[\`${test}_keys\`] = "";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const test = "Networks"
let onedata = JSON.parse(read_data);
onedata[test + '_keys'] = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 onedata[test+'_keys'] = "";
```

Like this :)